# Error con la importación de AngularFireModule

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, importación, firestore

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Angular, en el cual necesito hacer una conexión con Firestore. El problema que tengo es que al momento de importar "AngularFireModule" me muestra un error que dice: "'AngularFireModule' is declared but its value is never read.". Esto lo hago en el archivo module.ts. Tengo instalada la libreria de angular fire (versión 7.0.3).

Código en el module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthLayoutRoutes } from './auth-layout.routing';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire'; //Linea del error
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'

import { LoginComponent } from '../../pages/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../../pages/register/register.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AuthLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
    // NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthLayoutModule { }
```

Y este seria el package.json

```
    "@angular/fire": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "12.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.0.1"
  }
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

ese error es porque falta agregar tu modulo en la @NgModule, en el apartado de imports. Tu código debería quedar así:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
   AngularFireModule,
   CommonModule,
   RouterModule.forChild(AuthLayoutRoutes),
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
   // NgbModule
 ],´
```